# How to add total count of values in bar chart y-axis in time-series analysis graph in r

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

I have created a graph from two variables (customer.complaints and Date_by_month) for the trend chart of monthly granularity levels but on the y-axis, it's showing me the name of the complaints, instead of that I want the total number of complaints in that particular month. 
This is the graph I am getting 
[image]
as you can see the value of the y-axis it quite annoying. instead of that, I want to add the count of the values
Here is my code snippet

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

### Provide the trend chart for the number of complaints at monthly and daily granularity levels.
# converting date var to date type 
comcast$Date <- gsub('-', '/', comcast$Date)
comcast$Date <- as.Date(comcast$Date, '%d/%m/%Y')

# plotting graph for monthly granularity levels
comcast$Date_by_month <- as.Date(cut(comcast$Date, breaks='month'))
ggplot(comcast, aes(Date_by_month, Customer.Complaint)) + stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom='bar') + scale_x_date(labels=date_format("%Y-%m"), breaks='1 month') + scale_y_continuous(labels = fun.y= length)
```

Comment: Hello! Please can you provide some [reproductible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) data to work with? If they are confidential, can you reproduce the problem with any base R datasets (like `mtcars`)? I have a feeling it can be solved with `geom_text()` or some data pre-formatting.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues here. The code you posted actually has a syntax error in the last line so doesn't run at all : `scale_y_continuous(labels = fun.y= length)`, so whatever code produced your plot, it wasn't the code you posted.

In the line `stat_summary(fun.y=sum, geom='bar')` you are asking to get a *sum* of a text variable, which doesn't make any sense (maybe you meant `count` or `length`?)

And, of course, your problem isn't reproducible because you haven't given us any data to try it out on.

That said, let's recreate a similar data frame:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
library(scales)

random_words  <- function(x) paste0(sample(c(" ", " ", letters), 50, TRUE), collapse = "")
Date_by_month <- as.Date(as.POSIXct("2015-01-01") + months(sample(12, 100, TRUE)))
complaints    <- sapply(1:50, random_words)

comcast <- data.frame(Date_by_month = as_date(Date_by_month), Customer.Complaint = complaints) 

head(comcast)
#>   Date_by_month                                 Customer.Complaint
#> 1    2015-09-30 impzvcx esxfmknrpufewh   fxqknamay qhob cvpzlgubpu
#> 2    2015-08-31 mwt aezkcolutpengovtggeqavkxnfr myrq famttzzurj ug
#> 3    2015-04-30 uusewv wjxdpywsssqxgclhmlksrxqnqdfsip u jrdsfbldey
#> 4    2015-08-31 sf jytjtwseahfaqtvzisozuhhtrzygysxndyjifxoaytxhncf
#> 5    2015-06-30 vabtbfijnkeflhgpsspxyasiistuqqqjxuqs bsucp lbdrgbn
#> 6    2015-03-01 eylmurltlfgcp rvfdx as hiehnqdrn lrqanrmf quvzbhgh
```

Now, we don't actually need to include the complaints themselves in the chart. We can just give the dates to `ggplot` and it will automatically perform counts if we select `geom_bar`:

```
ggplot(comcast, aes(Date_by_month)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%m"), breaks='1 month')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>